# How do I intercept the binding from source to target?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Having a binding like this in XAML:

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorList}"
    />
```

I would like to "intercept" the update from the source (`ErrorList`) to the target and run my own code. For example, I may want to prevent the binding from occurring. Or, in my actual case, I would like to update the binding using the window's dispatcher (because `ErrorList` is changed in a different thread).

Interestingly, I can specify that I want to manually update the source by setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit`, but there isn't a similar property to specify that I want to update the target explicitly.

Comment: you can do that by adding a private variable to set the value in ViewModel and then if any changes need to be updated you can trigger OnPropertyChanged event.

Comment: One way is to create custom markup extension. Here guy creates delayed binding http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-delaybinding

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want to update target based on some business rule, so add a property like below,

```
 private List<Error>_ErrorList;
    public List<Error> ErrorList
    {
        get { return _ErrorList; }
        set
        {
            _ErrorList= value;                
        }
    }
```

Update your private object _activeListDocument when and where you needed and then call `NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorList");` to update your target.

Comment: That's a good solution, but do you think there's a way to keep the view model completely ignorant of how the binding is handled? In other words, can I do what I want without modifying the view model? For the example in my question, the view model holds an `ObservableCollection` called `ErrorList`, so updates are done through collection changed events.

Comment: @redcurry I dont think that would be a good solution. because `View` and `ViewModel` concept will broke if we are not letting `ViewModel` know what `View` has.

Comment: That's true, although isn't one concept of MVVM that the ViewModel doesn't know about the View?

Comment: @redcurry let it be any `View`, what to happen in `View`(any View) should be known by `ViewModel`, I mean `DataBinding`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use UpdateTarget on the BindingExpression and set Mode of the binding to One Time. But from your question it seems that you are accessing the Errorlist from a background thread (collecting error messages?) you could also use EnableCollectionSynchronization on the Binding to handle this.

If you can drop the thread safety requirement the following can add cross thread notifications.

```
public class SynchronizedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;

    public SynchronizedObservableCollection()
    {
        synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.OnCollectionChanged(e), null);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.OnPropertyChanged(e), null);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.ClearItems(), null);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.InsertItem(index, item), null);
    }

    protected override void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex), null);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.RemoveItem(index), null);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        synchronizationContext.Send((object state) => base.SetItem(index, item), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: `EnableCollectionSynchronization` seems like what I need, except I'm constrained to working with .NET 4.0.